# Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined with jade and backbone while it works with HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, pug, marionette

i have tried this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(41.63, -1),
zoom:5,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and it worked perfectly displaying the google maps image, but i have integrated this work to a bigger project made with Marionette and Jade, it shows : 
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined 
and doesn't charge whole the files of google Maps( like : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/23/5/map.js.) 
in my views.js i have wrote:

```
 mod.mapTemplate = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:_.template($('#actors-map-template').html()),
initialize: function () {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.63, -1),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(
    'googleMap'), mapProp);
},
onRender: function () {
  //this.initializemap();
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', this.initialize);
}
});
```

and in my jade page :

```
  #googleMap(style='width:500px;height:380px;')
```

the script is added in other file with all the scripts that are initialized of the whole app, i can't change the architecture, it is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

if someone get the same problem, here is how it worked for me : 
i have added two scripts in  the header  :
      script(src='/lib/google-maps/lib/Google.js')
      script(src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js')
and replace the variable map with this line : 
     var map = new google.maps.Map(this.$el[0], mapProp);
because it should read the element. 
but still a problem for render